# Alternative to .change in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fire an ajax event, and passing the value of select list options as arguments in the ajax call. Unfortunately, I'm firing the call on the .change event, and it is passing the values of the select option before the new option has been selected (i.e passing the previously selected options values). Is there an event which will get the current values of the option selected? Much thanks in advance,

```
<select id='theList'>
   <option> Option 1</option>
   <option> Option 2</option>
</select>
```

In the JS:

```
$('#theList').change( function() {
$.getJSON('Home/MethodName', { var1: Option1Value, var2: MiscValue}, function(data) {
      //Execute instructions here
}
)});
```

I wanted to use .trigger, but I think that fires beforehand as well.

Comment: how are you getting the values in the select event? `$(this).val();` should properly reflect the new value that fired the event. [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZaEQN/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think .change() is what you want, but you're misusing it. The change event fires after the value has changed. In your handler, you need to read the new value:

```
$('#theList').change( function() {
  var value = $('#theList').val();
  $.getJSON('Home/MethodName', { your_key: value }, function(data) {
      // ...
  }
)});
```

You also might want to set values on your `<option>` tags:

```
<option value="something"> Option 2</option>
```

Comment: You don't _need_ to set values; it will use the text if no value is set.

Comment: @Barmar TIL! Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You must be doing something wrong when getting the current select value. The following works correctly for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/TJ2eS/

```
<select id="demo">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>

$("#demo").change(function() {
    alert("current select value " + $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A word of warning, `.change` is now defunct, you should use...

```
.on('change', function()
```

Like that.